# Multiplying two Fourier series gives one Fourier series, but what are the new coefficients?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

If I have $A(x)=B(x) C(x)$ (sine periodic from 0 to 1) rewritten as

$\sum_n A_n \sin(n \pi x)=\sum_m B_m \sin(m \pi x)\sum_p C_p \sin(p \pi x)$

is there any easier way to compute $A_n$ from $B_m,C_p$ other than

$A_n=\sum_m \sum_p B_m  C_p\int_0^1 \sin(n \pi x) \sin(m \pi x) \sin(p \pi x) dx$

?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps write everything in terms of complex exponentials, $e^{i n \pi x}$.

Comment: Or use your addition formulas 2sin(A)sin(B) = cos(A-B) - cos(A+B), etc. (Of course these are best remembered/checked using complex exponentials). Moreover, this approach will immediately tell you that the product of two Fourier sine series is not a sine series, which when you thihk about odd function times odd function equal even function is no surprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Gerald suggests, write things in terms of complex exponentials, and then the magic words are "convolution" and "Fast Fourier Transform".

Comment: I seem to have just realized, embarrassingly, that mathoverflow is for math research level questions. I apologize for using your time and resources but thank you for your help.